# Loss function in Keras/TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

My intent is to implement a custom loss function for training a model in Keras with TensorFlow as backend.

## Loss function

[image: Loss funtion from LoDNN paper]

> W and H represent, respectively, the width and height of the softmax
>   layer’s output, and N is the batch size. The variable p is the
>   probability predicted by the FCN for the correct class.

This loss function is from this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.03613.pdf).

In this implementation, `N is 4, W is 200 and H is 400`.
The output shape of the final layer is `(None, 400, 200, 2)`. A single label's shape is `(400, 200, 2)` where each channel represents a class.

## So far,

### A Numpy implementation:

Even though this is not useful in this context, this is what I wanted to implement as a loss function.

```
def loss_using_np(y_true, y_pred):
    '''
    Assuming, `y_true` and `y_pred` shape is (400, 200, 2).
    This might change to (None, 400, 200, 2) while training in batch?
    '''
    dx = 0.0000000000000001 # Very small value to avoid -infinity while taking log
    y_pred = y_pred + dx
    class_one_pred = y_pred[:, :, 0]
    class_two_pred = y_pred[:, :, 1]
    class_one_mask = y_true[:, :, 0] == 1.0
    class_two_mask = y_true[:, :, 1] == 1.0
    class_one_correct_prob_sum = np.sum(np.log(class_one_pred[class_one_mask]))
    class_two_correct_prob_sum = np.sum(np.log(class_two_pred[class_two_mask]))
    N = 4
    H = 400
    W = 200
    return -1 * ((class_one_correct_prob_sum + class_two_correct_prob_sum) / ( N * H * W))
```

Above implementation gives an expected output; bad that it cannot be used.

```
y_true = np.random.randint(2, size=(400, 200, 2))
y_pred = np.random.random((400, 200, 2))
loss_using_np(y_true, y_pred)
```

### Failed try 01

```
import tensorflow as tf # not a good practice to not use keras.backend?
def loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
    # Not a working solution as it raises
    # ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[311146,3,400,2] BUT WHY?
    N = 4 # batch size
    W = 200
    H = 400
    dx = 0.0000000000000001
    y_pred = tf.add(y_pred, dx)
    class_one_gt = y_true[:,:,:,0]
    class_one_mask = tf.where(tf.equal(class_one_gt, 1.0))
    # Bad to use `tf.gather`. Issues warning,
    #`Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape.`
    class_one_prob_sum = keras.backend.sum(keras.backend.log(tf.gather(y_pred[:,:,:,0], class_one_mask)))
    class_two_gt = y_true[:,:,:,1]
    class_two_mask = tf.where(tf.equal(class_two_gt, 1.0))
    class_two_prob_sum = keras.backend.sum(keras.backend.log(tf.gather(y_pred[:,:,1], class_two_mask)))
    print("This will be printed only once; won't be printed everytime loss is callculated. How to log?")
    return -1 * ((class_one_prob_sum + class_two_prob_sum)/ (N * W * H))
```

### Failed try 02?

```
def loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
    N = 4
    H = 400
    W = 200
    dx = tf.constant(0.0000000000000001, dtype=tf.float32)
    correct_probs = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, tf.equal(y_true, 1.0))
    correct_probs = tf.add(correct_probs, dx)
    return (-1 * keras.backend.sum(keras.backend.log(correct_probs))) /(N * H * W)
```

For this #02 approach I'm getting a warning,

```
UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
  "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "
```

## Questions

1. Can you tell me how to implement this loss function without any warning? I'm not confident that #02 is the right implementation. I'm looking for an optimized solution. Any help or pointers is much appreciated.
2. I tried to understand what's happening inside `loss_function()` using `print` statements but, they are printed once while I `compile` the model. Is there any way we can log this?

> As mentioned by @dennis-ec, one can use [`tf.Print()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print) for
>   debugging.

## Side note

I'm using `Keras 2.1.4` with `TensorFlow 1.4.0-rc1` and `Python 3.5.2`.

Comment: If you feel this info is not sufficient, please do ask.

Comment: Idon't see your OOM but this is how you can print tensors during execution: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print . But printing the shapes during compiling of the tensors should also be sufficient to find the OOM tensor.

Comment: @dennis-ec any pointers on how to implement the loss function?

Comment: Not really. But don't focus too hard on keras.backend. It's nice if the backend has all the functions you need, but tensorflow has many more and it's not guaranteed that you can implement your function with keras.backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it seems like the authors are using a vanilla binary cross-entropy loss for multi-label classification. They also name it as such, but their definition is a bit odd compared to how you would implement it in Keras.

Basically, you could use `binary_crossentropy` as a loss function and supply the labels as arrays of shape `(400, 200, 1)` where a 0 denotes the first class and a 1 denotes the second class. The output of your network would then be of the same shape, with `sigmoid` activation functions at each output node. This is how semantic segmentation models are usually implemented in Keras. See [this repo](https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet/blob/master/model.py) for an example:

```
# final layer, sigmoid activations
conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)
model = Model(input = inputs, output = conv10)
# binary_crossentropy loss for multi-label classification
model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

This should give exactly the same result as with the implementation defined in the paper (they did probably not use Keras).

Comment: Thank you for answering; this is a life saver. You are right authors implemented the model in PyTorch. They have used `softmax` as activation for the final layer. Is there any particular reason that you suggested to use `sigmoid`? Should I assume since this is a binary classification, `sigmoid` is good enough?

Comment: Yes you can see it as a binary classification task for each pixel. Keras will automatically distribute the loss over all the output nodes (you have one node per pixel) and calculate the overall loss as the average. The reason why this works is because the softmax is just a generalization of the sigmoid function to multiple classes. If you have two classes, taking a softmax over two logits is equivalent to taking a sigmoid over one logit. The former will produce two probabilities which sum to 1, the latter will produce one probability, which sums to 1 with the probability of the negative class.

Comment: If you had more than two classes, you would need a softmax to implement it.